# Elementary5.0 installation problem _ This screen shows my headache

Tags: release-juno, system-installation

[image]
I want to ask, I saw this screen when I installed it with usb.

If you switch to ubuntu18.04, you will have the same problem.

Although you can continue to install down, there will be serious errors in the end (the actual error is not clear because of the blur)

I suspect that n graphics card is not supported, or the screen is 144 Hz (this is my personal guess)

May I ask if I have any suggestions for my question?

There is also a problem iso 1.48 GB is the size provided by the elementary official website, but the actual download is 1.37 GB

Is it normal?

10/2 18.20 supplement

When I have the above situation again, I directly unplug the usb and the screen will display normally (although I can't continue the installation to force the shutdown)

So I have guessed that the USB flash drive problem (the drive itself is brand new), so I tested it with FlashTester.

No problem with results.

After that, I tried other usb holes and found that the front plate has the same problem, so it is not a separate problem with the usb hole.

Another point, I am using dp line transmission.

Comment: Have you actually installed? I suspect the flickering might be fixed by installing the proprietary Nvidia driver (of it is an Nvidia card)

Comment: Size difference is normal. It's explained by the difference between Gigabyte and Gibibyte [see here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Difference-between-GiB-and-GB). Plus 1.48 Gigabytes is 1.378 Gibibytes. About the rest, can you expand a bit your question? We would need to know the graphics card model. Also, did you try to connect the screen to another port (or using another cable) ?

Comment: I did not install successfully.
Use gtx1060.
I don't have any other transmission lines or monitors.
I currently plan to use the Core graphics card to connect the display.
May buy a new monitor try.

Comment: try booting the usb with nomodeset, here is a link of how to do it
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10017/4710
this helps some times when you have problems with the graphic drivers