# Can I install elementary OS 5.1 on a Razer Blade Pro 17?

Tags: system-installation, release-hera

I am trying to install elementary OS 5.1, but I can never go into live boot on my Razer Blade Pro 17 4k 120hz laptop. The screen just goes black and shows some tearing. I tried doing `nomodeset` but still nothing works.

Comment: To be sure, if I understand correctly the tearings happens when there is GRUB, when you have to choose to test elementary OS or to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the [**nomodeset trick**](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10000/elementary-os-wont-boot-past-live-cd-screen) works 99.999% of the time. Can you confirm you tried this way?

Also, when booting from the USB media, please try both UEFI and BIOS with and w/o 'nomodeset' to see if there are different behaviors.

thanks!
-Aldo